# Pycharm keeps indexing

Tags: pycharm

For some reason Pycharm keeps indexing over and over. I have a program which needs to read a lot of files (>12,000, 5 mb per file) and Pycharm just keeps indexing.

Furthermore, I create these files (12000 files) on a daily basis, and the indexing takes up to 2 hours. Can someone explain how I can resolve this?

I have tried googling for any solution, but I cant find any. Which either implies that no solutions exists or I am bad at googling...
Can someone please help me!

Comment: Did you try to exclude the directory containing these files (right-click on the directory in the project tree -> mark as -> excluded)?